# Can some exotic sphere be diffeomorphically embedded into some $R^n$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, embeddings

Can some (or perhaps every) exotic sphere be diffeomorphically embedded into some $R^n$? How does such an embedding (if it exists) look like? I.e., what are the equations for a particular embedding?

Note that the answer to the related question [Can one give an immersion of exotic sphere $S^7$ in a standard sphere $S^8$ of radius $1$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/134479/) is only about immersions, which leaves my question open.

Based on the comment of Ryan Budney I found the desired explicit description in:
E. Brieskorn, Beispiele zur Differentialtopologie von Singularitäten, Invent. Math. 2 (1966), 1–14. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01403388

Comment: Wouldn't the Whitney embedding theorem apply to an exotic sphere?

Comment: Yes, exotic spheres, like all smooth manifolds, can be embedded in a euclidean space.  Exotic spheres can be embedded in quite low-dimensional euclidean spaces, for the most part.  Exotic $n$-spheres rarely embed in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ but they often embed in $\mathbb R^{n+2}$. In fact the answer may very well be "always" but I don't recall a proof (or a citation, if there is one).

Comment: In which sense "how does it look like"?

Comment: @ZevChonoles: Isn't the Whitney embedding theorem only for homeomorphic embeddings? I am asking for a smooth embedding.

Comment: It is for smooth embeddings. Not topological embeddings.

Comment: An exotic n-sphere topologically embeds in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$, and its image is $\{(x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_n) : \sum_i x_i^2 = 1 \}$.

Comment: The canonical co-dimension two embeddings of exotic spheres are among the Brieskorn varieties. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brieskorn_manifold